# Details on Starship's Reaction Control System thrusters

Tags: spacex-starship, rcs

Recent renderings of the proposed lunar starship has stirred speculation about what those 12 small landing engines are, half way up the space ship. In guessing they may be the same engines being developed for attitude control, I realized I have found very little information on those engines. 
At various times Musk comments have told me the RCS thrusters are methane / oxygen pressure fed engines using compressed gas tanks. They were working on the star hopper test fight, so they actually exist. That's all I have been able to gather.

So my question is; please give any additional information on these little buggers. Do they have a name? Are there pictures of them? What is the thrust, ISP? I also wonder if there are limits to how long they can operate due to cooling or fuel tank capacity etc. 
Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "...please give any additional information on these little buggers. Do they have a name?" I think you've just given them one! :-)

Comment: Your question has become more important as of now, since Starship is apparently unable to control its attitude in space...